# With XDebug enabled [] Operator not supported for strings error occurs sometimes when operand is an empty array

Tags: php, xdebug

I found this trouble while working with one of the Payment methods in store, and seems like a PHP interpreter bug or some feature that I'm not aware of.

Recently we moved to PHP7.2 and one of the payment methods came with this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /var/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 990
```

Here's the code:

```php
protected function _loadModelAttributes($object)
    {
        if (!$object->getId()) {
            return $this;
        }

        Varien_Profiler::start('__EAV_LOAD_MODEL_ATTRIBUTES__');

        $selects = array();
        foreach (array_keys($this->getAttributesByTable()) as $table) {
            $attribute = current($this->_attributesByTable[$table]);
            $eavType = $attribute->getBackendType();
            $select = $this->_getLoadAttributesSelect($object, $table);
            $selects[$eavType][] = $this->_addLoadAttributesSelectFields($select, $table, $eavType);
        }
        $selectGroups = Mage::getResourceHelper('eav')->getLoadAttributesSelectGroups($selects);
        foreach ($selectGroups as $selects) {
            if (!empty($selects)) {
                $select = $this->_prepareLoadSelect($selects);
                $values = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
                foreach ($values as $valueRow) {
                    $this->_setAttributeValue($object, $valueRow);
                }
            }
        }

        Varien_Profiler::stop('__EAV_LOAD_MODEL_ATTRIBUTES__');

        return $this;
    }
```

But as you can see with XDebug, the operand is an empty array, without any string in it. I tried to repeat that in interactive mode, but it's working alright with my PHP version.

[image: XDebug breakpoint on the line that causes error]

Moreover, it's one of the most common-used methods in Magento 1, and it's ok if it's called from any other module or part of the code. So the error occurs only with that particular call trace.

Obviously, error is not thrown if we're declaring an array explicitly:

```php
$selects[$eavType] = array();
$selects[$eavType][] = $this->_addLoadAttributesSelectFields($select, $table, $eavType);
```

But the fact that the error occurs make me think that there's something wrong with implicit `array_push` declaration in PHP7.2 interpreter.

Any ideas what could cause it? Some kind of scope or global variables issues? Is it worth to dig deeper and report a PHP7.2 bug or should I check something I maybe didn't notice?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 1:

I added some type checks and `var_dump` because I think XDebug is not always accurate. But the result is more weird than I could expect.

So here's the debug code:

```php
$selects = array();
        foreach (array_keys($this->getAttributesByTable()) as $table) {
            $attribute = current($this->_attributesByTable[$table]);
            $eavType = $attribute->getBackendType();
            $select = $this->_getLoadAttributesSelect($object, $table);

            echo gettype($selects);
            var_dump($selects);
            echo gettype($selects[$eavType]);

            $selects[$eavType][] = $this->_addLoadAttributesSelectFields($select, $table, $eavType);
        }
```

And here's the result:

```
array
/var/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php:992:
array (size=0)
  empty
string
```

[image: Execution result]

As you can see, the type of one of the keys in **empty** array is a  **string** (`gettype($selects[$eavType])`). How could that happen?

UPDATE 2:

Seems like it's XDebug-related bug. Everything is alright if you're not loading XDebug extension, but the error may happen even if you have XDebug disabled but loaded. Will keep question opened for some time because somebody may face similar issue and it seems much easier to communicate here.

Comment: Thanks for editing @dstrants! How can I add the code to the question keeping image? I think code says even more, because it's clear from code that there's no possibility that `$selects` is string.

Comment: I think it worth to notice that this happens on both production, development and my local environment -- PHP 7.2.15 on Red Hat and Ubuntu Linux, so it doesn't seems like some kind of server-related anomaly.

Comment: Are you 100% certain you are seeing the error on _this exact code_? It's kinda clear what state would cause that error (`$selects['key'] = 'foo'; $selects['key'][] = 'bar'`), but I absolutely can't see how _this_ code would possibly result in such state. You could try adding preemptive check for string with log to try figure out what is the state at the moment of error.

Comment: @Rarst you can make sure by looking at this mirror repo, it wasn't changed recently by any updates so I do have exactly same code: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php#L990. As the error says it's thrown exactly right there, but I think you can agree that it's almost impossible. I'm thinking that maybe it's possible that PHP interpreter checks data type before memory allocation for new array? Well there will be memory access violation then. Not sure how it works, but genuinely have no idea why is that happening.

Comment: Hey @Rarst, if you're still interested I've added some debug code and results. To be honest, it seems to rise much more questions than answers, because `var_dump` says it's an empty array, but `gettype($selects[$eavType])` says that I have string by that key in this empty array! Maybe it's some kind of GC issue?

Comment: I made PHP bug report for that issue (Bug #77678) https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77678. Was unable to find anything similar.